# Parallel programming with threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

> Parallel programming was possible in Java only from Java 7 with the
>   advent of `Join/Fork framework`.

Let's say in Java, using `ExecutorService` I create a thread pool of say 4 threads and submit to it say 10 tasks which means 4 threads will start executing the 4 tasks and other 6 tasks will be picked up by threads as and when any thread finishes its task.

Let's assume I have a quad processor having 4 cores, I know a thread can be run on a single core(not taking hyper-threading concept here) so will all my 4 threads work in parallel, 1 thread running on 1 core? Isn't it a parallel programming?

**EDIT:** [Source of reading](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLMod1hYiIvSZL1xclvHcsV2dMiminf19x)  - This is the Java 8 playlist where in chapter 1 it was referred that parallel programming was possible from Java 7 onwards.

Comment: "I read that parallel programming was possible in Java only from Java 7 with the advent of Join/Fork framework." that is wrong. You could use threads since Java1.0. The framework just makes stuff easier to use.

Comment: if you are not convinced with answers, probably you need to put your source where you read that. That would make easier for others to answer with full context.

Comment: Also note that you can find out the number of cores programmatically: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759570/finding-number-of-cores-in-java (sometimes people do +1 or -1)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a misconception on your end.

> I read that parallel programming was possible in Java only from Java 7 with the advent of Join/Fork framework.

That is wrong. The Join/Fork statement is simply *yet another* abstraction layer that gives you more powerful concepts to work with - compared to "bare metal" threads.

> Isn't it a parallel programming?

You have outlined clearly that your tasks will go into a pool that supports 4 threads; and that your hardware should support 4 threads as well. So that work will happen in parallel. And please not: *Fork/Join* is *not* the same as *ExecutorService*. Instead, both are advanced concepts; intended to make "parallel programming" easier for you.

After briefly listening into the video linked in the question: the tutorial  is about the fact that Java8 *added* streams, and on top of that *parallel streams* (which use the Fork/Join framework underneath - that one was introduced with Java 7).

In any case, that video emphasizes that parallel program gets *much much* **simpler** compared to earlier versions of Java. So it is not at all about introducing something that wasn't possible before - but about providing new *more* powerful abstractions that make it *easier* to do such things.

Comment: I have posted the link from where I got this wrong information. So just to be on same page, the example which I gave above of executing 10 tasks with 4 threads on 4-core processor is doing parallel programming. Right?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specifc? first video, after minute 5, 10, 15, ?

Comment: `ForkJoinPool`, part of the Fork/Join framework *is* an `ExecutorService`. And creating four thread to be executed on four cores is the best you can do trying to achieve the parallel execution, but there is never any guaranty that the threads will get executed that way…

Answer (score 3):

> Parallel programming was possible in Java only from Java 7 with the advent of Join/Fork framework.

Parallel programming exists in java since early versions. It was enhanced with Java 5 java.util.concurrent package classes and Java 7 ForkJoinPool further enhanced parallel programming to new level.

You can find answer to your questions in this [article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/fork-join-422606.html) by oracle.

Java Platform, Standard Edition (Java SE) 5 and then Java SE 6 introduced a set of packages providing powerful ***concurrency*** building blocks. Java SE 7 further enhanced them by adding support for ***parallelism***

Example of divide and conquer problem:

**Find sum of integers in large array**

Instead of sequentially computing the sum, divide array into multiple partitions and assign computation task on each partition to different task.

[image]

*The problem with the executors for implementing divide and conquer algorithms is not related to creating subtasks, because a `Callable` is free to submit a new subtask to its executor and wait for its result in a synchronous or asynchronous fashion*.

**The issue is that of parallelism:** When a `Callable` waits for the result of another `Callable`, it is put in a waiting state, thus wasting an opportunity to handle another `Callable` queued for execution.

The ***fork/join*** framework added to the **java.util.concurrent package in Java SE 7**

**Additions for Supporting Parallelism:**

The core addition is a new `ForkJoinPool` executor that is dedicated to running instances implementing ForkJoinTask. `ForkJoinTask` objects support the creation of subtasks plus waiting for the subtasks to complete. With those clear semantics, the executor is able to dispatch tasks among its internal threads pool by “**stealing**” jobs when a task is waiting for another task to complete and there are pending tasks to be run.

ForkJoinTask objects feature two specific methods:

The `fork()` method allows a `ForkJoinTask` to be planned for asynchronous execution. This allows a new `ForkJoinTask` to be launched from an existing one.

In turn, the `join()` method allows a `ForkJoinTask` to wait for the completion of another one.

[image]